# Problem with \part (memoir)

Tags: memoir, parts

I would like to design a \part text like this:

(Graphic)

Part title: {Annuntio laudam Tuam}

(smaller subtitle): Unterweisungen und Predigten

How do I do this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
% partpageprob.tex SE 645999

\documentclass{memoir}

\renewcommand{\partpageend}{} %% can write after part title

\begin{document}

\part[Part title]{\raisebox{0.5in}{GRAPHIC}\\ Part title}

\begin{center}
  \textbf{Smaller subtitle}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Almost, but I still can't put the jpg file.

The jpg file (a pair of wings) should be on top of this \part page. 

Could you please help me with that?

Thank you in advance and thanks for your help so far.

Comment: @Brayanokles see Simon Dispa's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using Peter Wilson's answer

[image: c]

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\renewcommand{\partpageend}{} %% can write after part title
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{showframe}% only to show the margins

\renewcommand{\beforepartskip}{% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{example-image} 
        \par\vfill
}

\begin{document}
    
    \part{Annuntio laudam Tuam}
    
    \begin{center}
        \textbf{Unterweisungen und Predigten}
        \vfill
    \end{center}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!